# Google search showing webpage name as Home(current) instead of page name

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have used bootstrap 4 to design my webapp. When i search my webapp on google, google returns Home(current) as the website name.However, the same search on Bing and Yahoo search engines works well and renders the website name as is.I have tried changing the bootstrap Navbar with no success.

when i search google this is what i get
[image]

The Navbar code looks like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
</div>
```

I expect google to return the webapp name rather than Home(current). e.g., as seen on bing "afroscholar-subject" as can be seen below;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need some SEO to know how show that information.

[Search Engine Optimization (SEO) Starter Guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en)

So, first for all, you need the proper meta tags:

```
 <head>
  <title>The title you want</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="words that google search in his motor to find you">
  <meta name="description" content="The description text google show when any search you.">
 </head>
```